# After Ubuntu 13.04 update all drivers crashed

Tags: drivers, 13.04

After updating Ubuntu all menus and dock on desktop disappeared. Video drivers and Internet crashed. apt-get upgrade doesn't work because I have no connection.

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be possible that the upgrade failed for some reasons? Did you notice any error messages?

For your current situation I see at least two possible solutions:

- Connect the affected system to the Internet and run apt-get
  dist-upgrade and/or apt-get install -f.
- Save your data with the help of an external storage device (e.g.
  smartphone, USB stick) and reinstall.